# Not able to fetch the gmail address book in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios7, gmail

From last few days i am stuck as i am not able to access my gmail address book in my iPhone app.I searched a lot but didn't get any success.
Here is the link that i refereed 
[I checked this link also to access gmail contacts](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1#running_the_sample_code)

In the above link it is given that  you can access the contacts using this url
**https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/userEmail/full**
I am able to login using GData framework but didn't find anything to fetch gmail contacts.
I have a access token after successful login and i am calling this method after logging in successfully.

```
- (void)doAnAuthenticatedAPIFetch {
    NSString *urlStr = @"https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/myEmailId@gmail.com/full";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.authToken authorizeRequest:request
              completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                  NSString *output = nil;
                  if (error) {
                      output = [error description];
                  } else {
                      NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                      NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                           returningResponse:&response
                                                                       error:&error];
                      if (data) {
                          // API fetch succeeded :Here I am getti
                          output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                      } else {
                          // fetch failed
                          output = [error description];
                      }
                  }
              }];

}
```

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this URL to get gmail account address book fetching.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction

And take instruction from here how to use google api.

http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/

hope this would be work for you.

Comment: i have used these link also,able to login but not able to fetch gmail address book